# How to describe one to many relationship (JPA/HIbernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I am having some trouble describing a one-to-many relationship with JPA. The problem that I am facing is that I think I should be able to save the `one` side of the relationship and have the `many` side receive the newly create id for the `one` side.

Here is a general schema of the problem domain:

```
Item ::= {
   *id,
   name
}

ItemCost ::= {
    *itemId,
    *startDate,
    cost
}
* indicates PK
```

In the above schema an item will have a cost for some given amount of time. It will only have one cost for that time period thus this is a one-to-many relationship.

This is where I get into trouble. Here is how go about describing the relationship with POJOs and JPA and am getting myself stuck.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Item", schema = "dbo")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Set<ItemCost> costs = new HashSet<>(0);

    public Item() {

    }

    public Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id.itemId")
    public Set<ItemCost> getCosts() {
        return costs;
    }

    public void setCosts(Set<ItemCost> costs) {
        this.costs = costs;
    }

    public void addCost(Date date, int amount) {
        getCosts().add(new ItemCost(date, amount));
    }
}
```

In the Item class I have described the fields that represent the schema plus an additional field for the relationship. Since the relationship is one-to-many I have added that annotation and instructed it to cascade all as I want it save, update, delete etc its children when it is changed. Additionally, I have added the mappedBy attribute to the annotation to indicate that I want to relationship bound by the id->itemId fields in the ItemCost (I think this is where my assumption is wrong: I am assuming this instructs the JPA provider, in this case Hibernate, that upon save I want the item id to be placed into the ItmmCost at this location before propagating the save).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ItemCost", schema = "dbo")
public class ItemCost implements Serializable {

    private Id id;
    private int cost;

    public ItemCost() {
        id = new Id();
    }

    public ItemCost(Date startDate, int cost) {
        id = new Id();
        id.setStartDate(startDate);
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    @Column(name = "cost")
    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(int cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class Id implements Serializable {

        private int itemId;
        private Date startDate;

        public Id() {

        }

        public Id(Date startDate) {
            this.startDate = startDate;
        }

        @Column(name = "itemId")
        public int getItemId() {
            return itemId;
        }

        public void setItemId(int itemId) {
            this.itemId = itemId;
        }

        @Column(name = "startDate")
        public Date getStartDate() {
            return startDate;
        }

        public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
            this.startDate = startDate;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 3;
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            final Id other = (Id) obj;
            if (this.itemId != other.itemId)
                return false;
            if (!Objects.equals(this.startDate, other.startDate))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I have additionally filled out the Item save with its field `cost` and additionally with its primary key of `itemId` and `startDate`. This is an embedded id as that seems to best describe the scenario with a compound id. Additionally, I may need to pass around this identifier in the future.

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

Item item = new Item("A Jar");
item.addCost(new Date(), 10);

em.persist(item);
em.getTransaction().commit();

em = emf.createEntityManager();
item = em.find(Item.class, item.getId());
Assert.assertNotNull(item);
assertThat(item.getCosts().size(), is(1)); // fails here with a result of 0
```

The test is rather strait forward and fails on the very last line. If I look at the db I am getting an entry in the ItemCost table but it has an itemId of zero (the default value of int in java).

Since, the cascade is saving I figure that my assumption about the `mappedBy` is inccorect. Is there some piece of meta data that is missing that will help inform the JPA provider that it should apply the `Item.Id` value to the children defined in the mapping?

Comment: you need to define the joincolumn `@ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "some_id")` in the inverse, but I am not sure if it will work because you are using an embedded class

Comment: `private Item parent;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("itemId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "itemId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Item getItem() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setItem(Item parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }`

If I add that code to the ItemCost with no other changes I get the following error:
`attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [testOneToMany.ItemCost.item]`

Comment: do you set the Item before saving it or is this property null? I think you will need to change the test code... it wont work if you only set the property that has the mappedby

Comment: Ok, that would violate the premise of the question. The mapping should take care of that relationship. If I am setting the properties by hand what good is the ORM tool?

Comment: it is still better than write all the sql :) anyway check the item **2.2.5.3.1.1. Bidirectional** in [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168) I think this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider updating your classes in the following way (the assumption is that PROPERTY access is used):

```java
public class Item implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "item") //non-owning side
    public Set<ItemCost> getCosts() {
        return costs;
    }
}
```

```java
public class ItemCost implements Serializable {
    private Item item;

    @ManyToOne //owning side
    @JoinColumn(name = "itemId") //the foreign key (the primary key of "Item")
    @MapsId("itemId")    //is shared with the compound primary key of "ItemCost"
    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

Additionally you would need to set up bidirectional relationship, i.e.

```java
em.getTransaction().begin();
Item item = new Item("A Jar");
// item.addCost(new Date(), 7);
ItemCost itemcost = new ItemCost(new Date(), 7);
itemcost.setItem(item); //owning side
item.getCosts().add(itemcost); //non-owning side
em.persist(item);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

The above will produce:

```
INSERT INTO Item (id, Name) VALUES (1, 'A Jar')
INSERT INTO ItemCost (cost, startDate, itemId) VALUES (7, 2014-04-08 22:50:00, 1)
```

---

Side notes (regarding your compound primary key class):

1. Don't use setter methods on compound primary key class specified with `@EmbeddedId` or `@ClassId` annotation (once it has been constructed it should not be changed), according to Effective Java, Item 15: Minimize mutability:

   > An immutable class is simply a class whose instances cannot be modified.
   >   All the information contained in each instance is provided when is
   >   created and is fixed for the lifetime of the object. (...) To make
   >   class immutable, follow these five rules:
   >
   > 1. Don't provide any methods that modify the object's state
   > 2. Ensure that the class can't be extended
   > 3. Make all fields final
   > 4. Make all fields private
   > 5. Ensure exclusive access to any mutable components.

   I believe a compound primary key class fits perfectly into this rule.
2. Specify `@Temporal` annotation for `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` persistent fields, according to JPA 2.0 Specification, chapter 11.1.47 Temporal Annotation:

   > The `Temporal` annotation must be specified for persistent fields or
   >   properties of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar. It may only
   >   be specified for fields or properties of these types.

   Annotating `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` types with `@Temporal`
   indicates  which of the corresponding JDBC `java.sql` types to use when communication with JDBC driver (i.e. `TemporalType.DATE` maps to `java.sql.Date` and so on). Of course, if you use `java.sql` types in your entity classes then the annotation is no longer required (I am not aware of these types from your code snippets).

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for but it is the answer that is correct. The problem is that I do not want to have to specify an entity in the ID. Hibernate forces this behavior and as such your answer is spot on. 

I don't agree with your first side notes especially for compound keys with more than two fields. In general you are correct but in particular I disagree. 

What is the benefit of adding @Temporal?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Just to clarify your statement: "_The problem is that I do not want to have to specify an entity in the ID_"? Do you want to preserve unidirectional association from `Item` entity (remove `Item` from `ItemCost` entity)?

Comment: Ok, because the parent portion of the ID is the parent itself it does make sense make the id's fields final. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @wypieprz I have a similar question.  Are you willing to help me with it?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316761/duplicate-entry-string1-string2-for-key-primary